# How to know whether spark job completed successfully or not in shell script?

Tags: shell, apache-spark

I am submitting my spark job using shell script and I want to know that my spark job completed successfully or not. If spark job completed successfully then I want do some operations on data written by job in HDFS otherwise exit from shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are submitting it via shell script you can just check the status of your command via `$?` and then proceed with next steps.

```
./spark-submit ......

 if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
 #DosomethingHere
 else
 #DoSomethingHere
 fi
```

Comment: This will work based on status of spark job but sometime It happens that your job stopped due to logical error or exception at that time the status of spark job may be success so at that time the above logic will not work.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar Dhakad  so how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Using Spark REST API, you can get the status of the Submitted Spark Applications.

Excerpt from the Spark Documentation:

In the API, an application is referenced by its application ID, [app-id]. When running on YARN, each application may have multiple attempts, but there are attempt IDs only for applications in cluster mode, not applications in client mode. Applications in YARN cluster mode can be identified by their [attempt-id]. In the API listed below, when running in YARN cluster mode, [app-id] will actually be [base-app-id]/[attempt-id], where [base-app-id] is the YARN application ID.

For the Running application: http://localhost:4040/api/v1
and for the history server: http://:18080/api/v1

?status=[active|complete|pending|failed] list only stages in the state.